# How to make sure LuaTeX write all that is supposed to?

Tags: xetex, luatex, lua

I have a file

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\( \mathaccent"7017 c \)
\end{document}
```

that prints what is supposed to, a C-with a circle on top in math-mode, just fine.

Suppose now I switch the file over to a font that does **not** have the character, like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\( \mathaccent"7017 c \)
\end{document}
```

xelatex exits with an error message:

```
! Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'
```

and does not write the PDF file.

On the other hand `lualatex` exits silently and writes a PDF file with the `c` and no accent -- which is very hard to determine if this is an occurrence in a large document.

How can one determine if luatex is printing what is supposed to?

Comment: You can set `\tracinglostchars=2` and see "Missing character" warnings on the terminal and the log file.

Comment: as wipet says you can set tracinglostchars (the xetex message looks like a xetex bug) but you should never have a numeric `\mathaccent`  command like that in a latex document,  the latex math symbol declarations abstract away the numbers so you can specify a ring accent  in a way that uses the right slot for the encoding being used.

Comment: https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2021-June/027968.html